# Reading from stdin in assembly using fgets

Tags: assembly

I started to learn new stuff about assembly language and currently I want to make a simple code using fgets and __iob function to read from stdin.

Here I found the __iob[0] function :
http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html

I want to put my string from input into eax, but my code crashes.

I tried something like this:

```
xor eax, eax 
call __iob
push eax
call _fgets
pop eax
```

Comment: Why are you looking at AVR studio documentation if you're programming for x86? `stdin` is typically == 0.

Comment: `fgets()` needs 3 arguments.

Comment: @Michael File discripter of standard input is typically `0`, but `stdin` for `fgets()` won't be 0, which means `NULL`.